# ListBox does not use all available space within Grid.Column - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, listbox, grid-layout

I have a ListBox control that has been assigned to Grid.Column 0 which has a value of '*' defined for it's width, however when rendered there is a sizeable amount of space that is not being used.

I have also noticed that there is a border of sorts around the ListBox control itself, however I have not added one within the markup.

My UI (Areas of concern marked in Red):

[image]

My Markup:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GameImagesTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="{Binding FileInfo.FullName}" Margin="8,8,8,8" Height="70" Width="70" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Width="70" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="GameTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Background="Gray" FontSize="16" />
                <ListBox x:Name="imageContent" ItemsSource="{Binding FileList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GameImagesTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="ContentList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GameTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="DarkGray">
            <Button Click="OnLoad">_Load</Button>
            <Button Click="OnSave">_Save</Button>
            <Button Click="OnAdd">_Add</Button>
            <Button Click="OnDelete">_Delete</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

How would I go about resolving both of the issues raised. Is it the default behaviour of the ListBox control?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the default behavior.

In the case of the alignment it looks like you have a `WrapPanel` in each `ListBoxItem` which doesn't have quite enough space to put another item on line 1. The remaining space is unused because of the `HorizontalContentAlignment` setting on `ListBox` defaulting to Left. This setting is in turn bound to by the default `ListBoxItem`. Setting `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on your `ListBox` should fix that.

The outer border comes from the default setting for `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness`. Setting `BorderThickness="0"` will get rid of it entirely.

There are some other default `Padding` settings that add some spacing in the default Styles and Templates. If you want to get more into those add a `ListBox` to a project in Blend and make a copy of its default `Template` and `ItemContainerStyle` and check out the XAML. Also consider using the base `ItemsControl` in cases where you don't need selection behavior, as it doesn't have any of these type of default settings.

Comment: Thanks John, your suggestions did the trick. My previous implementation used the ItemsControl but I decided that selection functionality is quite a desirable features of mine. This may be a bit of a broad question but is extending/customising the default Control Styles/Templates encouraged for WPF?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it's overkill. If you can make the changes you need without doing it then you'll still get the benefit of the native styles on different OS's.